# How to sort a Map and a Set containing all the words that begin with ‘A?

Tags: java

First of all I have class that has one static array of countries:

```
public class Countries {
public static final String [][] DATA = {
        {"ALGERIA","Algiers"}, {"ANGOLA","Luanda"},
         {"BENIN","Porto-Novo"}, {"BOTSWANA","Gaberone"},
         {"BURKINA FASO","Ouagadougou"},
         {"BURUNDI","Bujumbura"},

          // other countries and cities

         {"URUGUAY","Montevideo"}, {"VENEZUELA","Caracas"}, 
};}
```

The generic interface that produces next set value:

```
public interface Generator <T> {
public T next ();}
```

The generic class with two parameters:

```
public class Cities <Country, City> {
Country country;
City city;

public Cities (Country country, City city){
    this.country = country; this.city = city;
}}
```

The following class has several method "CompareTo" and I woule like to find out how to compare two char variables:

```
public class GeneratorOfCities implements Generator <Cities <String, String>>, Iterable <Integer>, Comparable <java.lang.Character> {
private Random rand = new Random ();
private int count = 0;
private char MyChar = 'A';
private int size = 10;

@Override // Create its own version of iterator.
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Iterator <Integer> (){

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return count <= size;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return count ++;
        }
    };
}

@Override // Produces new instance of specified class
public Cities<String, String> next() {
    int index = rand.nextInt(Countries.DATA.length);
    return new Cities (Countries.DATA[index][0], Countries.DATA[index][1]);
}

@Override // How to compare two char values and return a word that begin with 'A'?
public int compareTo(Character o) {
    return (o.compareTo(MyChar));
}}
```

MainClass has a counstructor with two args and the static method that return an instance of MainClass:

```
public class MainClass <A, B> extends LinkedHashMap <A, B>{

public MainClass (Generator <Cities <A, B>> gen, int size){
    for (int i=0; i!=size; i++){
        Cities <A, B> pp = gen.next();
        put (pp.country, pp.city);
    }
}

public static <A, B> MainClass <A, B> MC (Generator <Cities <A, B>> gen, int size){
    return new MainClass (gen, size);
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    System.out.println(MainClass.MC(new GeneratorOfCities(), 10));
}}
```

It works correctly, but I need to produce LinkedHashMap array that has words begin with 'A' character.
PS:
I'm trying to do an exercise from the book "Thinking in Java" 4th edition, page: 597-601;

Comment: shouldnt class country have string name, string capital????

Comment: May I suggest an `if` statement inside the loop in your MainClass constructor?

Comment: The Exercise 2:  Produce a Map and a Set containing all the countries that begin with ‘A’.  Yes, you are right,  I need to use String array.

Comment: Thanks  VGR, but I had tried to do it already and it didn't no work. I need another way to solve this problem :(